# how many can use nested entity class in odata service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing like [ODataServiceSample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ReadMe.txt) project

It's says,you can request from client for nested entity :

```
var query = ctx.ProductFamilies.Where(p => p.ID == 3).SelectMany(p => p.Products);
```

And server side, support for /ProductFamilies(1)/Products:

```
ProductFamiliesController : EntitySetController<ProductFamily, int>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Support for /ProductFamilies(1)/Products
    /// </summary>
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return _db.ProductFamilies.Where(pf => pf.ID == key).SelectMany(pf => pf.Products);
    }
}
```

how to do support for /ProductFamilies(1)/Products(1)/BatchNumbers on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another EntitySetController for Product and do exactly the same as you did for ProductFamily entity set, i.e.:

```
ProductsController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Support for /Products(1)/BatchNumbers
   /// </summary>
   [Queryable]
   public IQueryable<BatchNumber> GetBatchNumberss([FromODataUri] int key)
   {
       return _db.Products.Where(p => p.ID == key).SelectMany(p => p.BatchNumbers);
   }
}
```